# How to make a transparent picturebox click through?

Tags: vb.net, transparency, click-through

I want to make the picture-box in a form to be transparent and click through.

[image]

In the above image, yellow areas are the picture-boxes and Red area is the form. Form area should be transparent but not click through. Picture-boxes should be transparent and click-through. How can I achieve this ? I am doing my project in VB.net (VS2010,.NET 4)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to make the background of your form invisible where as picture boxes to be visible. If I am right you can use the following code to make the background of the form invisible:

```
Public Sub InitializeMyForm()
     BackColor = Color.White
     TransparencyKey = BackColor
End Sub
```

Now you can add code for the click events of the picture boxes or the "Red Area" to make it click through.

Comment: No thats not what I want. I want the picture boxes and the form to be invisible. But only the form area should be click-through